# How to add else condition to takeIf in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I know that for checking

```
 if(storesList!=null && storesList.isNotEmpty()){
    // do this 
    } else {
  //else do this
    }
```

we can write like this,

```
storesList?.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }.apply {//do this
  }
```

How can i add an else condition to this, I'm not taking about `takeUnless`

Comment: @Raghunandan can you please post an answer for that,

Comment: Not able to figure out where you want to put **else condition**? inside **takeIf** block or after that operation?

Comment: @JeelVankhede I want to convert the old if else to the new kotlin type `takeif`, i have posted my condition above

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Kotlin way, you can use **safe call operator** ('**?**') to do stuffs on nullable objects without crash or even making it inside `if (obj!=null)` block.

So, some object like

```
if (someObj != null )
    someObj.someOperation() //just doing some operation
```

is the same thing by calling like : `someObj?.someOperation()`.

---

So, if you want to check emptiness of list without **if-else condition**, you can use like below *(Which you've already done)*.

```
storesList?.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }?.apply { 
    // Provides you list if not empty
}
```

But what about else condition here?

For that, you can use **elvis operator** to satisfy condition. What this operator do is if left hand-side of operation is null or doesn't satisfy specific condition then take right hand-side of operand.

So, final code should look like:

```
storesList?.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }?.apply { 
// Provides you list if not empty
} ?: run {
// Else condition here
}
```

Explanation: if `storesList` is **empty or null** it goes to else part *(that is after elvis)* otherwise goes to **apply block**.

Comment: ?: // Else condition here when i add braces here, i'm getting mismatch unit/boolean

Comment: You can put `run { }` block there.

Comment: The null-coalescing operator (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator) in Kotlin is `?:`, not `?.`.

Answer (score 10):

You can add an Elvis Operator..

```
storesList?.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }?.apply {
    //it.isNotEmpty() is true
} ?: //it.isNotEmpty() is false
```

So if `it.isNotEmpty()` is true, `takeIf` returns a non-null value and the apply block will be called.

If false, the expression is null and the elvis operator will execute the expression behind it. The elvis operator is a bit like `if (expression before == null)` -> execute statement after elvis operator.

For more information, have a look at the docs: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator

Comment: i was not able to add braces after ?: which causes mismatch unit/boolean

Comment: Well this is the only disadvantage.. You'd have to wrap it in a function...

Answer (score 5):

> Use Elvis Operator

eg.)   `a ?: b // here if`a`is not null value =a else value=`b

in your case -

```
storesList?.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }?.apply {
    //it.isNotEmpty() is true
} ?: run{} //`else condition goes here`
```

for more check here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator